# change image size(width) by jquery or css

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, css

how can changed image size in  mouse

example

from

[image]

to

[image]

Comment: Please, try to be more clear. You want to do that on mouse hover? click? you want to trim the image?

Comment: i want in mose hover `A` only show me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This is one way to do it using HTML/CSS/JQuery:

**[See this code in action via jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/85catLny/).**

**THE HTML**

```
<div id="image_frame">
    <div class="shrinking_image"></div>
</div>
```

**THE JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#image_frame").hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find(".shrinking_image").addClass("image_frame_hover");
        }, 
        function(){
             $(this).find(".shrinking_image").removeClass("image_frame_hover");
        });
});
```

**THE CSS**

```
#image_frame {
   width:167px; height:27px; 
}

.shrinking_image {
    background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9MCk.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:0px 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:167px; height:27px;
}

.image_frame_hover {
    overflow:hidden;
    background-position:-70px 0px !important;
    width: 24px !important;
}
```

**[See this code in action via jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/85catLny/).**

Basically, you are just using jQuery's `hover()` function to assign and un-assign a special css that uses the a combination of the css properties `width`, `height` and `background-position` to show only the parts of the photo you care about.

**Hope this helps!**